# Method threw 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException' exception

Tags: java, http, ssl, junit, wiremock

I have written a JUnit to test one of the method which calls below getAuthToken

```java
public String getAuthToken() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    String formBody = String.format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&scope=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(clientId, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            URLEncoder.encode(clientSecret, StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            URLEncoder.encode(scope, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    HttpRequest authRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI(epimTokenUri))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(formBody))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> authResponse = client.send(authRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(authResponse.body());

    return jsonNode.get("access_token").asText();
}
```

For this I am using WireMock. Following is mapping for WireMock for getting token

```json
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/.default/token"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "access_token": "testToken",
      "expires_in": 3600,
      "refresh_expires_in": 0,
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "not-before-policy": 0,
      "scope": "https://localhost:9082/.default"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  }
}
```

This gives error as method threw 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException' exception. at the line `HttpResponse<String> authResponse = client.send(authRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());`

Can anyone please help me on this? What is going wrong here or any other way to mock this method to use in my JUnit? Following is the complete stackTrace [image]

Comment: Please post the entire exception stacktrace.

Comment: Well, you obviously misconfigured SSL somewhere. Either, your application is expecting SSL, but you didn't configure it in Wiremock or you did enable SSL in Wiremock but did not specify a working SSL certificate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, i attached the screenshot for stacktrace. Is it helpful?

Comment: No, post the exception stacktrace as code-formatted **text** (use `exception.printStackTrace()`). That said, have you **read** the exception message, it identifies the problem for you, your connection is not actual SSL encrypted, but just plain text.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how to fix this? connection should be plain text instead of SSL encrypted or it is otherwise?

Comment: Somewhere you're saying a connection is HTTPS, while it is actually is HTTP.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , you are right my tokenURI in test.yaml file was https so was expecting certs, replaced with http. It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my test.yaml file tokenURI was with https, so it was expecting certs which I was not providing through WireMock. I replaced it with http, and it passed. Another way to solve this is to setup WireMock with certs to accept SSL.